# Не могу найти нужный файл на centos linux

Tags: linux, centos

Как включить автодополнение для всех пользователей BASH. На ubuntu, если я не ошибаюсь, надо отредактировать файл /etc/bash.bashrc, но я не могу найти его на centos. Вопрос в том есть ли он вообще, и если да, то где он?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Bash#Configuration_files. Если нет файла, то попробуйте создать.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте воспользоваться поиском:

```
find ./<path> -name bash.bashrc
```

Вообще, если я вас правильно понял, вы ищите .bashrc файл. Он скрытый и обычным `ls` вы его не увидите, вам нужен `ls -a`.

Также можете глянуть [эту тему](https://superuser.com/questions/943348/whats-the-equivalent-of-bashrc-for-centos), там люди ищут эквивалент .bashrc